# How to configure JOOQ to codegen tables with the same structure?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I have some legacy tables with the same structure in MySQL like:

```
my_table_01
my_table_02
my_table_03
...
```

Is there a way I can configure JOOQ codegen to generate only one table/record class which shared by all those tables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps that you have to do in order to achieve what you like to do:

#### 1. Configure the code generator

You'll probably have to exclude `my_table_02` and `my_table_03` from being generated. You can do this by specifying [the `<excludes/>` tag as documented here](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration/).

Optionally, you could use [generator strategies (programmatic config)](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/) or [matcher strategies (XML config)](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy/) to rename `my_table_01` to `my_table`.

#### 2. Configure your runtime

While running queries against `MY_TABLE`, you can specify [runtime table mapping](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/runtime-schema-mapping/) in order to map `MY_TABLE` back to `my_table_01` or `my_table_02` or `my_table_03`. This mapping works on a per-configuration basis, i.e. it will have the scope of a single query if you're using one configuration per query.

Another option is, of course, to abstract over these suffixes in your client code, e.g. via a table selection method:

```
public static Table<?> myTable() {
    if (something)
        return DSL.table("{0}_01", MY_TABLE);
    else if (somethingElse)
        return DSL.table("{0}_02", MY_TABLE);
    ...
}
```